# Checkout repository to existing working copy in Cornerstone 2?

Tags: macos, svn, versions, working-copy, cornerstone

I have several remote repositories that I have been previously working with using Versions for OS X. I am thinking about moving to Cornerstone 2 and am currently evaluating it, and I want add all my repositories to it. However I want to, if possible, check them out to the same working copies that I created in Versions.

I thought that I could do this by just checking out the repository to the same directory and naming it the same as the existing copy's root folder, and it would just use whatever was in there, however when I try it, I get this error:

"Description : '/the/directory/path/to/working/copy' is already a working copy for a different URL
 Suggestion : The operation could not be completed.

Technical Information
  Error : V4Error  Exception : ZSVNException

Causal Information
Description : '/the/directory/path/to/working/copy' is already a working copy for a different URL
     Status : 155000
       File : subversion/libsvn_client/checkout.c, 206"

However, when I check the repository details in Versions, the repository URL's are exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved, just was an issue with the repository itself not with Cornerstone, after re creating my local copy I was able to able to check out with no issues.